# Can not login after npm update Firebase

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase, access-token

I updated firebase to "firebase": "^4.2.0". Seems like the user's object properties changed.

```js
const loginGG = () => {

  try {
    firebase.initializeApp(clientCredentials)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('firebase is already created')
  }
  return firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
    .then(result => {
      if(!result || !result.user) throw new Error('LOGIN ERROR')
      const token = result.user.ze;
      const user = result.user;

      Cookies.set('tapId', token);
      Cookies.set('tapUser', JSON.stringify(user));
      history.go(-1);

      return {
        user,
        token
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      return {}
    });
}
```

so I changed 'result.user.ie' to 'result.user.ze'. I know there is another way to generate the token because on firebase doc they say 'Use User.getToken() instead.' I tried and no success. Maybe someone who has experienced it can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

`.ze` or `.ie` sound like non public fields, as you said, you could use the `getToken` method. which returns a promise resolving with the jwt token. something like

```
user.getToken().then(token => {/* do something with the token*/})
```

see the firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getToken):